# It is possible to change nginx 'index' dynamically based on first segment of URL after domain address

Tags: php, nginx

I have set root in nginx file: **/var/www/html/public**,

My domain is example.com.

I want to achieve that if I type **example.com/first** it will run **/var/www/html/public/first.php** file.

If I type **example.com/second** it will run **/var/www/html/public/second.php**.

If I type **example.com/third** it will run **/var/www/html/public/third.php**.

It is even possible?

Comment: You could search here for "extensionless php" - there are many solutions.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Richard Smith give me huge support by his advise. I search about extension-less php, and because not everyone know this (like me before) I paste my nginx config, which do exactly what i wanted to achieve.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /vagrant/public;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name your_domain_name; #for example example.com

    location / {
         try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
         index index.php index.html;
    }
    location @extensionless-php {
         rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    # You must use this, because if You not use it, You will get surce code instead of result of php script execution.
    location ~ \.php(/|$)  {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```